# How to access a class declared inside another class without creating an instance?

Tags: c#, class

I have a 'Table' class. inside this class I have another class called 'Filter'. I want to create an instance of Table and access Filter like this:

```
Table t = new Table();
t.Filter.Add();
```

How should I declare Filter class? I think its not a good idea to declare static because Filter must work on Table instance. what should I do?
This is my class:

```
 public class Table : Database
    {
        public class Filter 
        {
            private List<BaseClasses.DataTypes.FilterCondition> conditions = new List<BaseClasses.DataTypes.FilterCondition>();

            public void Add(string column, Int64 value)
            {
                conditions.Add(new BaseClasses.DataTypes.FilterCondition(column, "=", value.ToString()));
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173120.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class Table : Database
{
    public Filter Filter 
    {
       get;set;
    }

    public Table()
    {
        Filter = new Filter();
    }

    public class Filter
    {
        private List conditions = new List();
        public void Add(string column, Int64 value)
        {
            conditions.Add(new BaseClasses.DataTypes.FilterCondition(column, "=", value.ToString()));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Create the `public class Filter` inside `Table` and add a property called `Filter` to `Table`, like so:

```
public Filter Filter { get; set; }
```

Comment: @K.B: You answered wrong, and edited your answer after viewing mine. But hey, I'm ok with that. It's not about the points, it's about helping each other out, isn't it?

Comment: no that's not true I posted the code first and I added the description

Answer (score 1):

Just make your class as a property of the table class

```
 public class Filter 
            {
                private List<BaseClasses.DataTypes.FilterCondition> conditions = new List<BaseClasses.DataTypes.FilterCondition>();

                public void Add(string column, Int64 value)
                {
                    conditions.Add(new BaseClasses.DataTypes.FilterCondition(column, "=", value.ToString()));
                }
            }
```

and here your table class

```
public class Table : Database
        {

    public  Filter Filter  {get;set;}

    }
```

Comment: whaaaaaaaaaaaaaaat are you OK

Comment: I'm great. The question is, are you OK, @JulieShannon?